# Unity Raycast when hover and press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

how to use raycast when hover and press on object. 
The only method I could come up with is using 2 raycast. 
But only 1 raycast works, depending on the order in which they are checked.

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));                                                                    
                Ray ray1 = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();

                if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5))
                 if(Physics.Raycast(ray1, out hit, 5))
                 {
                   ...
                 }
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try creating another RaycastHit variable and passing it to the second raycast statement.

The way you are using it the hit variable will be useless.. Also there might be a better way of doing what you're trying to do.

Can you explain your scenario a bit better?

Comment: Thanks, but creating another RaycastHit doesn't help. I'm trying to make Raycast work when the camera is aimed at an object and click on an object.

Comment: Maybe this will help

RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) 
{
            Transform objectHit = hit.transform;
            
            // Do something with the object that was hit by the raycast.
}

Comment: This is only suitable for pc, but I'm trying to do on android.